# Bitdefender accusing viruses while compiling c++ source with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, antivirus, false-positive, bitdefender

I'm using Bitdefender few years ago, and CodeBlocks for some time, and today specifically the programs were not compiling, until I saw that BitDefender was accusing virus (Gen: Variant.Symmi.86658) in any compiled program, even in a new project with Hello World.

I did a boot scan with a BitDefender boot recovery, but it did not find anything. Meanwhile, the problem continues.

My question is: Will it be a false positive? Should I disable programs generated by CodeBlocks to not be intercepted by BitDefender? Or is my Windows infected in some way invisible to Bitdefender?

I also deactivated Bitdefender for a few minutes, generated an .exe and submitted it to VirusTotal, which accused a lot of problems: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ca86a72936301bb4199857fe4ed194eb6aaeb7d5dde1d3822c1e00acaec4763a/analysis/1526009068/

Comment: Nightmare scenario: Have you made certain that your compiler has not been subverted to insert a virus payload into everything it compiles?

Comment: what compiler though? `Gen:` doesn't mean that it is virus, it means that program got a feature shared with known viruses

Comment: I use the MinGW, standard.
The curious thing is that this problem started yesterday and I always used CodeBlocks and Bitdefender without problem. It may be that the last update of the Bitdefender database left it with this new feature and started from there to accuse false positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a Bitdefender repair (uninstall and reinstall), updating the entire virus database.
This solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but using Geany, Bitdefender, and MinGw compiler on Windows10, in my case i solved this using bitdefender's complete scan (it found some trojans out from my programming directory). Then and i had to reinstall bitdefender, after a viruses manage it does not refresh databases by itself unless you install it again.